# opencv/python: mask in module cv2 while streaming webcam video

Tags: python, opencv, webcam, mask

Hey everyone I'm trying to make a game using my webcam where I need some objects to fall down the screen while Im streaming video with my webcam (that stream being my background).

I am using **python and module cv2** of opencv

The question is: how do I apply a mask to this objects? I already have an image to be the mask of the original image but I dont know how to apply it to subtract the background of the original image..

ive already tried using the cv2.bitwise_and but nothing happened, the imaged stayed the same with black background:

```
#targets
original_ball = cv2.imread("Aqua-Ball-Red-icon.png")
ball = cv2.resize(bola_original, (64,64), fx=1, fy=1)
#mask
mask_original = cv2.imread("input-mask.png",0)
mask = cv2.resize(mask_original, (64,64), fx=1, fy=1)
res = cv2.bitwise_and(ball, ball, mask = mask)
```

Thanks in advance!

Comment: What are the 0/1 values of your mask?

Comment: Since you told about the game, have you checked the module 'pygame'?

Comment: yes I already did but I already made the entire game using opencv (cv2 module) and numpy, the only problem that I have is with the mask of the targets in the game

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you're using `cv2`, you're working with `numpy` arrays, and there's no need to turn to opencv for something as simple as a mask.

First, manipulate (multiply, possibly) your mask array so that the values you want (i.e.: those not masked out) have value 1. Then, multiply your source image by your mask. That will make the resulting image have the original pixels where the mask == 1, and 0 (i.e.:black) where the mask == 0.

Here's the gist of it:

```
import numpy
original_ball = cv2.imread("Aqua-Ball-Red-icon.png")
ball = cv2.resize(bola_original, (64,64), fx=1, fy=1)
mask_original = cv2.imread("input-mask.png",0)
mask = cv2.resize(mask_original, (64,64), fx=1, fy=1)

max_value= numpy.max(mask)
mask/=max_value
res= ball*mask
```

Depending on the color depth of your *input-mask.png*, you may need to reduce it to grayscale first

Comment: Thanks, that made sense. But now I'm getting an error that I dont understand:

'res = ball*mask 
ValueError: operands could not be broadcast together with shapes (64,64,3) (64,64)'
Does this means that the two images have different shapes? is it because of the flag 0 added in

'mask_original = cv2.imread("input-mask.png", 0)'

what am I doing wrong?

Answer (score 1):

The mask was not appearing because of the 0 argument next to the name of the mask image).